# How to login to Tumblr with API v2?

Tags: c#, oauth, tumblr

My app used to be able to log into Tumblr, but late last year they changed their api to use OAuth. I am having a hell of a time trying to log in to Tumblr programmatically from a client-side app.  I am using [this app](https://github.com/stoiveyp/DashBuddyWin) as a guide.  Everything seems all right, but I keep getting `Missing or invalid request token` from Tumblr.

My question is this: is there an actual working example of logging in to Tumblr via OAuth in C#?

Answer (score 0):

[Temboo](http://temboo.com) simplifies the OAuth process for Tumblr by breaking it down into two calls:

- `InitializeOAuth` - returns a Tumblr authorization URL that you can show to your users and have them grant your application access to their Tumblr account.
- `FinalizeOAuth` - returns the access tokens your app needs for authenticated access to Tumblr accounts.

You can experiment with Temboo's Tumblr OAuth support in your browser from the link below, and then generate the source code you need to use this behavior in your app with the Temboo SDK. If your language isn't supported (Temboo does not currently have a C# SDK), you can generate REST API cURL commands.

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Tumblr/OAuth/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)

Comment: Hi Cormac ,I am using rest sharp(C#) for posting text on tumblr but getting error .can you suggest the way to using temboo Rest API curl command.

Comment: Hi Shailesh, I replied to your Temboo support ticket with details on how to use the Temboo REST API.